# How to retrieve a page "info" tab from PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get the basic information array on this page http://www.facebook.com/pages/Nichi-Vendola/38771508894?sk=info

I'm using FQL to get picture profile, fan counts and name:

```
$result = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => 'select fan_count, name, pic_square from page where page_id = '.$page_id.";"
));
```

But i can't figure out how to get informations like Work position or Religion..
I've also tried to use the page id as a user id but didn't work..
I haven't found anything about this on Facebook Developers, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to do.

1. Have the admin of the page authenticate you app with the `manage_pages` permission.
2. Call `me/accounts` and find the page in that list which will have a page access token.
3. Take page access token and query `/me?access_token={pageAccessToken}`

Try it out in the Graph API Explorer: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer